# Wifi/Bluetooth preventing my system to boot on PopOs 22.04

Tags: drivers, pop-os, hardware-compatibility

I'm quite new to Linux, and I'm having some problems with this WiFi/Bluetooth dongle adapter, which seems to work only if I unplug and then plug it back in. Can someone please help me? I'm really sad because I don't want to go back to Windows, since this window tiling is so good.

I already tried to install the RTL8821CU driver, but it does not change anything, and I still have to unplug and plug the dongle. I'm using PopOs 22.04 LTS

**inxi -Fxxxpmrz**

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.6.10-76060610-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS base: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: B550M Pro4 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: P2.10 date: 06/15/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: hidpp_battery_0 charge: 67% condition: N/A volts: 3.9 min: N/A
    model: Logitech G903 LIGHTSPEED Wireless Gaming Mouse w/ HERO type: N/A
    serial: <filter> status: Discharging
Memory:
  RAM: total: 31.27 GiB used: 4.93 GiB (15.8%)
  RAM Report:
    permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required.
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Zen 3 rev: 2 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2400 high: 3800 min/max: 2200/4850 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 2200 2: 2200 3: 2200 4: 2200 5: 2200 6: 2200 7: 2200 8: 2200
    9: 3800 10: 2200 11: 3800 12: 2200 13: 2200 14: 2200 15: 2200 16: 2200
    bogomips: 121370
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: nvidia v: 545.29.06 pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 ports:
    active: none off: HDMI-A-1 empty: DP-1,DP-2,DP-3 bus-ID: 06:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:2504 class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server:compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    display-ID: :1 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 81 s-size: 602x343mm (23.7x13.5")
    s-diag: 693mm (27.3")
  Monitor-1: HDMI-0 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 82 size: 598x336mm (23.5x13.2")
    diag: 686mm (27")
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 545.29.06 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 06:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:228e class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: ASRock
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 08:00.4 chip-ID: 1022:1487 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: Fifine Microphone type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 3-2.2:4 chip-ID: 3142:5060
    class-ID: 0300
  Device-4: Razer USA USB Sound Card type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 3-2.3:5 chip-ID: 1532:0529
    class-ID: 0300 serial: <filter>
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.6.10-76060610-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 1.0.2 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASRock driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
    port: f000 bus-ID: 05:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp5s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.38 TiB used: 19.95 GiB (1.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: KingSpec model: NE-512 size: 476.94 GiB
    speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: SVN9177
    temp: 33.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: Fanxiang model: S790 1TB size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: SN13683
    temp: 39.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 459.52 GiB used: 16.74 GiB (3.6%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1020 MiB used: 288.5 MiB (28.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
  ID-3: /recovery size: 3.99 GiB used: 2.92 GiB (73.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/dm-0 mapped: cryptswap
  ID-2: swap-2 type: zram size: 16 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: 1000
    dev: /dev/zram0
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: N/A mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 55 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0%
```

**dkms status**

```
nvidia/545.29.06, 6.6.10-76060610-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821cu/5.12.0.4, 6.6.10-76060610-generic, x86_64: installed
system76/1.0.14~1707324875~22.04~da04fd6, 6.6.10-76060610-generic, x86_64: installed
system76_acpi/1.0.2~1707324865~22.04~19ad0c5, 6.6.10-76060610-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
system76-io/1.0.3~1707324885~22.04~3dd4c32, 6.6.10-76060610-generic, x86_64: installed
```

[image: Cursed dongle]